# Android Studio 4.1 ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

When I switch to Android Studio 4.1 with this changes https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/pull/267/files

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha10'
```

I run into
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/pull/267/checks?check_run_id=737327676

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not create task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'.
      > Cannot obtain value from provider of environment variable 'ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE' at configuration time.
        Use a provider returned by 'forUseAtConfigurationTime()' instead.
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to get rid of it ?

Comment: I have the same issue and not able to understand it why ...

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-beta01' solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a [Google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158239278) for this

According to info in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157583088
If this the same issue it should be fixed in AGP 4.1 beta 1, which is tentatively scheduled to be released Wednesday June 10th at 10am Pacific Time.

Comment: It's solved with 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-beta01'

Answer (score 7):

Same issue for me.
It seems like Gradle issue (maybe should open a bug report)

I am able to temporary solve it by downgrade Gradle version to 6.5-milestone-1